# What does a colon within an map call mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Here is the example line from a working app file

```
   suppressionMap["survey:lifestyle:cigarettes"] = !(custData.survey[1].questions[0].answer == 'stillSmoke');
```

What do the : mean in "survery:lifestyle:cigareets:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.  It's just part of the key, just like any other letter.  And `suppressionMap` is not an array, it's a map (key/value).

Comment: Just to expand - keys are allowed to use these characters and more. But you cannot do `suppressionMap.survey:lifestyle:cigarettes` because that's a syntax error. Same if you have a dash - `obj.complex-key` will not be a syntax error but wouldn't be interpreted as "get me the value of the key called `complex-key` from `obj`" but instead "get me value of the key called `complex` and then subtract from it the value of the variable `key`"

Answer (score 2):

@Sam Alexander "survery:lifestyle:cigareets" is just the string name of the key in the `supressionMap` map